Spring-boot profile not working in prod war file
In my spring-boot project, I have set two profiles (local and prod). However, when I build a war file, the prod profile is not getting activated in the war package.
I have the following three properties file in my project.

application.properties
application-local.properties
application-prod.properties

Inside my pom.xml I have the following.
       <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>local</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
       <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <finalName>policy-backend</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

I am using the following command to build the war file.
   mvn clean -Pprod package 

I have a environment property (cors.allowed.origins) inside my application-local.properties and application-prod.properties file.
@Value("${cors.allowed.origins")
private String allowedOrigins;

When I run the project in my IntelliJ, it works fine and it reads the value from application-local.properties. However, when I build the war file using the above maven command, it throws and error while server startup complaining about the property not found.
Thanks for your time and help.

Maven profiles aren't Spring Profiles. And you shouldn't build different artifacts for different environments. Provide the profile to run in your Tomcat instance through environment variables.

@M.Deinum an you please explain me little bit more? how can i build a war file that takes the property from the application-prod.properties file?

You have to specify your profile through an option at startup like --spring.profiles.active=prod  The information is needed at runtime not build time
